# How to extend a pulse in system verilog

Tags: verilog, pulse, system-verilog

I am trying to make a very simple module in System Verilog that receives a short pulse as an input, and returns as an output a pulse which is twice wider. For example, if the input is a 1ns pulse, then I want the output to be 2ns pulse. A delayed output would be even better.

I thought of making a frequency divider, but that won't help here, since frequency divider works with clocks, which rise and fall all the time, in contrast to a pulse, which will rise only once.

Thank you!

Comment: Behavioral or for real? Also I am not yet sure what you mean with *"A delayed output would be even better"*.

Comment: A very simple module won’t be able to do what you want with any degree of accuracy or repeatability.

Answer (score 1):

As we have several people who say that it can't be done here is a behavioral solution :-)
Note that in real hardware it can't be done this way.

```
module pulse_double(
   input      pulse,
   output reg double_pulse
   );

time time_rise,time_elapsed;

   always @(posedge pulse)
      time_rise = $time;

   always @(negedge pulse)
   begin
     time_elapsed = $time - time_rise;
     double_pulse <= 1'b1;
     double_pulse <= #(2*time_elapsed) 1'b0;
  end
endmodule


module pulse_double_test;
integer loop;
reg  pulse_in;
wire pulse_out;

   pulse_double pulse_double_inst(
    .pulse(pulse_in),
    .double_pulse(pulse_out)
   );

  initial
  begin
     for (loop=0; loop<10; loop=loop+1)
     begin
        pulse_in <= 1'b1;
        #(($random & 32'h07)+32'h02); // width between 2 and 9 
        pulse_in <= 1'b0;
        #20;
     end
  end
endmodule
```

With the waveform:

[image]

This is a simple solution which works for non-overlapping input/output pulses. If input pulses can overlap with the output you have to define what behavior is wanted and then adapt the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As oldfart correctly points out: This answer applies to verilog meant to actually define hardware only; for simulation models, see his answer!

> For example, if the input is a 1ns pulse, then I want the output to be 2ns pulse

That's not among the abilities of verilog, as far as I can tell; since this is not a logical or clocked thing that you want, it's impossible to represent it in verilog.

However, let's rephrase:

> If the input is a pulse that lasts for N clock cycles, then I want the output to be 2N clock cycles long.

Then it's really just counters: one increasing a "must still be emitted count" by one per clock cycle as long as the input is high. You'd add minimal logic: The output is high as long as the input is high OR the counter > 0. Also, for as long as the input is low, and counter > 0, decrease counter by 1.

Done! All you need is clock that is at least as fast as the shortest pulse you want to deal with. But that's kind of a given, since this really is digital logic, and not analog circuitry.

Comment: Marcus, the first is also not problem if the code is behavioral. That is why I asked *"Behavioral or for real?"*

Comment: @Oldfart you're right, and I added a bit of prologue :)